# Parsing an integer in a string

Tags: c, io, scanf, fgets

I am trying to get an integer separated by space in a string, the sample input and outputs I expected are :
***i : word 1***
***o : 1***

***i : word 20***
***o : 20***

I tried doing it like this:

```
scanf("word %d", &num);
```

but it doesn't work.
I also tried this:

```
scanf("%[^/]*c%d", &num);
```

or

```
scanf("%[^/] %d", &num);
```

But still, none of them works. Can anyone give me a tip on how to do this? Thanks

Note : the output integer doesn't have a space in front of it.

Full code :

```
int t, num;
char word[1000];
int arr[100], arr2[100];
fgets(word, 1000, stdin);
scanf("%d", &t);
while(t--){
    scanf("word %d", &num);
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

As you can see in the above sample code, I am also taking more inputs before taking the input for `num`.

Comment: You try to get solution in C or C++ since these are different programming languages?

Comment: It's in C, sorry I didn't mention it

Comment: The first code should work.

Comment: `if(scanf("%*s%d", &number) == 1) { ... }`

Comment: *"I am also taking more inputs before taking the input for `num`."* Please show a short complete example of the full data input, and the output you are getting from code that "doesn't work."

Comment: @WeatherVane the code sample is above that phrase, and yes, it doesn't work with the OP tested solutions so I think its complete now.

Comment: @anastaciu yes, but I asked for a complete *data* sample, as OP says there is other processing that had to be done.

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code just needs a space before the `scanf` text sequence to discard any blank characters that are left in `stdin` from previous reads, you can, however, improve it further to recongize bad inputs and discard them if that is the case:

```
while(t){
    if(scanf(" word %d", &num) == 1){ //space before word
        printf("%d\n", num);
        t--;
    }
}
```

But if you want to use that regex specifier you cand do something like:

```
while(t){
    if(scanf("%*[^ ]%d", &num)){
        printf("%d\n", num);
        t--;
    }
}
```

This would work not only for *`word`* but for any other string, provided that it only has one word, *i.e.* no spaces, apart from the one in the end.

Comment: I'm sorry, It does work, but I didn't post the whole code. My code does take other inputs before taking input for the num, I've edited my question

Comment: @Gary02, you just need a space there, I edited my answer.